# Difference between "De Nada" and "No problema"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras

What is the difference between `De Nada` and `No es problema`? They both mean "no problem", or "it was nothing", right?

Comment: It should be "No **hay** problema" (or, alternatively, "ningún problema" or "sin problema"). Saying "No problema" is sort of [slang/pseudo-Spanish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_problemo), and sound really off. It actually reminds me of the Terminator 2 movie, when the kid teaches the terminator to tell people [_"No problemo"_](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103064/quotes?item=qt0416755) to talk "the way people talk".

Comment: @Diego, I meant "No es problema". I added the "es" to the sentence. :)

Comment: Though one could use "sin problema", which is rather common

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"De nada": It means like "you're welcome". When someone makes you a favor or provide help,  you say him thanks (gracias), and then he responds with "de nada".

"No problema": It's quite similar, the difference is that "No problema" is usually used before someone makes the favor, or give help.

Examples:

De nada:

> Gracias por ayudarme con mi tarea. -De nada, fue un placer.

No problema:

> Me puedes recoger del colegio a las 3:00. - Claro, no hay problema.

Comment: Gracias mucho!!! Yo entiendo ahora!!! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange!!! :)

Answer (score 6):

While "De nada" means "you are welcome", "No problema" is not a correct sentence in Spanish.

The correct way of using the second sentence would be: "No hay problema" or "No es problema" which literally translates into "No problem" and "it's not a problem" respectively.

Other than that, the difference between using one or another was well explained in the answer provided by @Nicolas.

Comment: I actually forgot to add the "es" in the sentence. I added it. Thanks! :)

Comment: De nada, I thought so.

Comment: _No hay problema_ sounds better than _No es problema_ (which sounds odd).

Comment: I agree on that. I was just giving different choices.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, but "No problem" isn't technically correct English either.  Language is fluid.

I hear Spanish speakers saying "No Problema", maybe they're influenced by cross-cultural contamination, but it just isn't true that no one says "No problema".

Answer (score 1):

Having lived three years in Mexico, I heard both "de nada" and "por nada" used for the English "you're welcome". "De" can mean either "from" or "of", while "por" means "for".

Things do not always translate literally between languages, but think of both of these as meaning "It was nothing", or "Don't mention it" in English.

Also, think of the poor Spanish speaker learning English, trying to figure out why they shouldn't mention something!